# formik-react Dynamic FieldArray onChange event

Tags: reactjs, formik

How to trigger onChange when the field changes on FieldArrray Item? Array items can be added. So is there a way in formik if the quantity field changes on Array 2 element just trigger for that item?

Only adding the relevant code section

```
  const FormObserver = (index) => {
   //This approach works but I will need to do the calculation for all field array items as I won't know which one triggered this change

    const { values:{InvoiceDetails} }  = useFormikContext();
   
    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log("FormObserver::values", InvoiceDetails);
      console.log(index);
    }, [InvoiceDetails]);

    return null;
  };





 return (
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    InvoiceNumber: '',
    InvoiceDate: Date.parse('2017-10-20'),
    ClientId: '',
    CompanyId: '',
    PaymentStatusId: '',
    PaymentTerms: '',
    Total: '',
    Notes: '',
    InvoiceDetails: [{
      Id: '',
      Description: '',
      Quantity: '',
      Amount: '',
      VatPercentage: '20',
      VatAmount: '10',
      Total: '100'
    }]
  }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    InvoiceNumber: Yup.string().required(),
    InvoiceDate: Yup.string().required(),
    ClientId: Yup.string().required(),
    CompanyId: Yup.string().required(),
    PaymentTerms: Yup.number().required().positive().integer().max(365),
    Notes: Yup.string().max(10),
    InvoiceDetails: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        Description: Yup.string().required("Description is a required field"),
        Quantity: twodecimalplaces("Quantity")
                  .required("Quantity is a required field")
                  .max(100000, "Maximum allowed Quantity is 100000"),
        Amount: twodecimalplaces("Amount")
          .required("Amount is a required field")
          .max(1000000, "Maximum allowed Amount is 1000000"),
        VatPercentage: Yup.number().positive().integer()
          .required("VatPercentage is a required field")
          .max(100, "Maximum allowed Percentage is 100"),
        VatAmount: Yup.number().required("VatAmount is a required field"),
        Total: Yup.number().required("Total is a required field")
      })
    )
  })
  }
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
  }}
>

  {({ props, values, setValues }) =>
  (

    <Container>
      <Form>


        {!invoicenumber && <h1 className="header text-center">Create new invoice</h1>}
        {invoicenumber && <h1 className="header text-center">Edit invoice</h1>}


        {!isAuthenticated && <Login></Login>}
        {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}

        {success && <Alert variant="success">{success}</Alert>}

        <Row>
          {/* <Field name="InvoiceNumber" component={InvoiceNumberV3} /> */}
          <InvoiceNumberV4 name="InvoiceNumber" />

          <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
            Date
          </FormControl.Label>
          <Col md={4}>
            <MyDatePicker name="InvoiceDate" />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row>
          <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
            Client
          </FormControl.Label>
          <Col>
            <FormSelect name="ClientId" options={clientItems.map((client) => ({ "value": client.Value, "key": client.Key }))} />
          </Col>
          <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
            Company
          </FormControl.Label>
          <Col>
            <FormSelect name="CompanyId" options={companyItems.map((company) => ({ "value": company.Value, "key": company.Key }))} />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row className="mt-2">
          <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
            Payment Terms
          </FormControl.Label>
          <Col>
            <DependentField name="PaymentTerms" type="text"></DependentField>
          </Col>

          <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
            Notes
          </FormControl.Label>
          <Col>
            <FieldV1 name="Notes" as="textarea" rows="3" ></FieldV1>
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <FieldArray name="info">
          {() =>
            values.InvoiceDetails.map((invoicedetail, index) => {
              return (
                  <Card className="mt-2" key={`detail-${index}`}>
                    <Card.Header as="h5" className="container-fluid">
                      Invoice details #{index + 1}

                      {index > 0 &&
                        <Button type='button' variant="danger" size="sm"
                          onClick={(e) => removeInvoiceDetail(index, values, setValues)}
                        >
                          Remove-{index}</Button>
                      }
                    </Card.Header>

                    <div className="mt-2 m-2">
                      {/* <FormObserver index={index} /> */}

                      <Row key={index}>
                        <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                          Description
                        </FormControl.Label>
                        <Col md={10}>
                          <FieldV1 name={`InvoiceDetails[${index}].Description`} ></FieldV1>
                        </Col>

                        <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                          Quantity
                        </FormControl.Label>
                        <Col md={4}>
                          <FieldV1 name={`InvoiceDetails[${index}].Quantity`} onBlur={(e)=>test()}></FieldV1>
                        </Col>

                        <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                          Amount
                        </FormControl.Label>
                        <Col md={4}>
                          <FieldV1 name={`InvoiceDetails[${index}].Amount`} ></FieldV1>
                        </Col>

                        <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                          Vat%
                        </FormControl.Label>
                        <Col lg={4}>
                          <FieldV1 name={`InvoiceDetails[${index}].VatPercentage`} ></FieldV1>
                        </Col>

                        <Row>
                          <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                            Vat Amount
                          </FormControl.Label>
                          <Col>
                            <FieldV1 readOnly={true} name={`InvoiceDetails[${index}].VatAmount`}></FieldV1>
                          </Col>

                          <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                            Total
                          </FormControl.Label>
                          <Col>
                            <FieldV1 readOnly={true} name={`InvoiceDetails[${index}].Total`} ></FieldV1>
                          </Col>
                        </Row>
                      </Row>
                    </div>
                  </Card>
              )
            })
          }
        </FieldArray>

        <div className="mt-4 mb-4 center-div">
          <Button type="submit" variant="success" size="lg" disabled={busy}>
            {busy && (
              <>
                <Spinner
                  as="span"
                  animation="border"
                  size="sm"
                  role="status"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
                <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
              </>
            )}
            Create Invoice
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="button"
            variant="secondary"
            size="lg"
            onClick={(e) => addInvoiceDetail(values, setValues)}
            disabled={busy}
            className='margin-left-1rem btn-block'
          >
            Add detail
          </Button>
          <Link to="/">
            <Button type="Button" variant="secondary" size="lg" disabled={busy} className='margin-left-1rem'>
              Back
            </Button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  )}
</Formik>
```